# content_for are not rendering in partial views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have a rails app which uses a layout

The simplified version looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render 'layouts/head' # renders the "layouts/_head.html.erb" partial correctly  
                              # the most head (css/js) content gets implemented here %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield # renders the current action %>

    <!-- implement alls scripts which should be exectued on the bottom of the page -->
    <%= content_for :scripts_bottom %>
  </body>
</html>
```

in my `layouts/_head.html.erb' I use

```
 <%= content_for :scripts_head %>
 <!-- it seems `content_for` instead of `yield` appends content -->
```

In my `partials` I place the following snippets to append them :scripts_head. (some of my partials should put javaScripts

```
<% content_for :scripts_head do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'some_script' %>
<% end %>
```

The content_for in the `layouts/head' renders nothing

*How can I resolve that?*

It looks like that `partials` are not able to append their content_for content when the `content_for :blah do` is placed BEHIND the echoing content_for / yield tag.

If I try try `content_for :scripts_bottom` it will get rendered at the bottom of the page.

Thanks in advance

Rails 3.2.14
ruby 2.0.0p247

Answer (score 0):

instead of `provide`, try `<%= content_for :scripts_head %>`

Comment: this was my first approach: Does not work. I correct that in my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `content_for` then you need to yield it in your head instead of render.

So your header would look like:

`<%= yield :scripts_head %>`

Alternatively you can remove the `content_for` in your partial and just have the JS by itself like this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'some_script' %>`

Then you wouldn't have to change your layout file.

Comment: the content_for seems to append multiple `content_for :blah do` blocks. That is my final goal. But it renders nothing. Not with `yield :blah`, nor `content_for :blah`

Answer (score 0):

In your `layouts/head` partial, use `yield :scripts_head`  not content_for